# How to use regex to extract boolean operators followed by words until the next operator?

Tags: javascript, regex, boolean, operators

I'm trying to put together a relatively simple expression for extracting boolean string operators (AND, OR, NOT, etc) coming from user input, in a way that the resulting array of matches would contain words and the preceding operator until the next operator:

```
const query = 'lorem AND ipsum dolor OR fizz NOT buzz';
```

results should be like:

```
[
 ['AND', 'ipsum dolor'],
 ['OR', 'fizz'],
 ['NOT', 'buzz']
]
```

I've created this for getting single words after each operator, which is fine:

```
^(\w+\s?)+?|(AND) (\w+)|(OR) (\w+)|(NOT) (\w+)
```

then tried to modify it to handle multiple words after an operator in order to obtain the above result, but its always greedy and captures the whole string input:

```
(AND|OR|NOT) (\w+\s?)+ (?:AND|OR|NOT)
```

#### UPDATE

I'we figured it out, but I'm not sure how pretty or efficient it is:

```
^(\w+)|(AND|OR|NOT) (.*?(?= AND|OR|NOT))|(AND|OR|NOT) .*?$
```

Comment: *"results should be like"* You really want to drop the leading text?

Comment: `\b((?:AND|OR|NOT)\b(?:.+?)(?=AND|OR|NOT|$))` would do it but there will be a better way I think.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, it does the job indeed, but I'm curious to see which would be the most efficient solution.

Comment: @AlexK. Actually I think, to me, this is one of the most appealing expression after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't htink you can get there *purely* with regular expressions in JavaScript, but you can get awfully close:

```js
const query = 'lorem AND ipsum dolor OR fizz NOT buzz';
const rex = /\b(AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\b(?:AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b)/ig;
const result = [...query.matchAll(rex)].map(([_, op, text]) => [op, text]);
console.log(result);
```

The regex `/\b(AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\b(?:AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b)/ig` looks for:

- A word break
- One of your operators (capturing it)
- A word break
- Zero or more whitespace chars (capturing them)
- A non-greedy match for anything
- Zero or more whitespace chars
- Either another operator or the end of the string

The `map` after the `matchAll` call is just there to remove the initial array entry (the one with the full text of the match). I've done it with destructuring, but you could use `slice` instead:

```
const result = [...query.matchAll(rex)].map(match => match.slice(1));
```

```js
const query = 'lorem AND ipsum dolor OR fizz NOT buzz';
const rex = /\b(AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\b(?:AND|OR|NOT|NEAR)\b)/ig;
const result = [...query.matchAll(rex)].map(match => match.slice(1));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Btw, is the second word break (before `\s*`) really necessary?

Comment: @EdmondTamas - Based on a few quick tests, it doesn't seem to be, though...truthfully I'm not sure why not. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You might also use a negative lookahead to assert that the word characters after so not start with either one of the alternatives

```
\b(AND|OR|NOT) ((?!AND|OR|NOT)\b\w+(?: (?!AND|OR|NOT)\w+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UwiZ2o/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(AND|OR|NOT) ((?!AND|OR|NOT)\b\w+(?: (?!AND|OR|NOT)\w+)*)/gm;
const str = `lorem AND ipsum dolor OR fizz NOT buzz`;
let m;
let result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  result.push([m[1], m[2]]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncapable of doing that with regexp but this is a super simple solution that could work.

```
let q = 'lorem AND ipsum dolor OR fizz NOT buzz';
let special = ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'];

let fullResult = [];
let skip = true;

q.split(' ').forEach( word => {
    if ( special.indexOf(word) !== -1 ) {
        fullResult.push([word]);
        skip = false;
    } else if (!skip){
        fullResult[fullResult.length-1].push(word);
    }
});

console.log(fullResult);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, indeed, you can work around it, however I would like to keep it simple and learn more about regex in the same time. Thanks!